# My app broke after firebase updated a breaking change

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework

> ```
> "dependencies": {
>     "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
>     "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
>     "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
>     "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
>     "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
>     "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "1.3.1",
>     "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
>     "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.0.0",
>     "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
>     "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
>     "cordova-support-android-plugin": "1.0.1",
>     "cordova-support-google-services": "1.3.1"
> },
> "cordova": {
>     "plugins": {
>         "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
>             "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
>         },
>         "cordova-support-google-services": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": {
>             "FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION": "16.0.+",
>             "FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "17.4.+",
>             "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
>         },
>         "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
>         "cordova-plugin-file": {}
>     },
>     "platforms": [
>         "android"
>     ]
> }
> ```

My app was building well, after firebase updated Update - May 07, 2019
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

my app cannot build anymore. it returns the following log:

> Dependency resolved to an incompatible version:
>   Dependency(fromArtifactVersion=ArtifactVersion(groupId=com.google.firebase,
>   artifactId=firebase-messaging, version=17.4.0),
>   toArtifact=Artifact(groupId=com.google.firebase,
>   artifactId=firebase-iid), toArtifactVersionString=[17.1.0])
>   :app:preReleaseBuild FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g.
>     "[17.1. 0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior
>     exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0 ->
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[17.1.0], but fire base-iid version
>   was 17.1.2.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the
>   issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.4.+
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s 14 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 13 up-to-date
>   /home/user/herot/herot-eyes/src-cordova/platforms/android/gradlew:
>   Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g.
>     "[17.1. 0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior
>     exhibited by the library will be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0 ->
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[17.1.0], but fire base-iid version
>   was 17.1.2.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the
>   issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.+
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.4.+
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s
>
> app:spawn Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1 +1ms 
>   app:cordova-conf ⚠️  [FAIL] Cordova CLI has failed +0ms  app:cordova
>   Shutting down Cordova process... +1ms

How can i solve this issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone found a workaround at the moment.
Just do this and it should fix your problem:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=26.1
```

**https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging/issues/82**